# Handling onblur events with angular

Tags: angular, typescript

With jQuery I can simply write something like

```
$(document).on("blur", ".class_name", function(){}
```

in order to trigger some function on blur event of `class_name` elements. How would I achieve the same results with angular?

Solvations like

```
<input (blur)='on_blur_function()'.... >
```

are not acceptable for my case, unfortunately. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily:

import and inject ElementRef into the constructor

```
constructor(private elem: ElementRef){}
```

Search the elements using querySelectorAll api.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.class_name');
    elements.forEach(element => {
     // you can iterate through each element and call your function
     this.on_blur_function(); // call your function
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Directive and use the class as its selector :

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: ".foo"
})
export class BlurredDirective {
  @HostListener("blur")
  blurred() {
    console.log("blurred");
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

In your template :

```
<input class="foo" >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a directive, you can have an isolated approach using `ViewChildren` in combination with a template reference variable:

```js
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  OnDestroy,
  QueryList,
  ViewChildren
} from "@angular/core";
import { fromEvent, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <input #inputRef />
    <input #inputRef />
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChildren("inputRef") elements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngUnsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elements.forEach(element => {
      fromEvent(element.nativeElement, "blur")
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))
        .subscribe((event: FocusEvent) => this.customBlurEvent(event));
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe$.next();
  }

  customBlurEvent(event: FocusEvent) {
    console.log({ event });
  }
}
```

By adding `#inputRef` to the inputs, you can query it after the view was initialized inside `ngAfterViewInit`. `rxjs` has an observable creator named `fromEvent`, which takes a source and an event type, in this case, the inputs and the blur event. You can then dispatch your method with the event, unsubscribing from the event source when the component gets destroyed (hence my call to `takeUntil` to avoid memory leaks).